# How to create a missing java class?

Tags: java, swing, class, netbeans

I have an application with three classes (`MainClass`, `ClassA` and `ClassB`). The `MainClass` runs with no problem, but when I try to run `ClassA` or `ClassB`, I get the following stacktrace message:

`Error: Could not find or load main class myPackage.ClassA` or `Error: Could not find or load main class myPackage.ClassB`

When I looked in the `build` folder, the `MainClass.class` file was there, but there was no `ClassA.class` or `ClassB.class` files, which I am sure is causing the problem.

I tried creating those classes from scratch but it didn't fix the problem, and I tried performing a clean and build but it keeps on failing so that hasn't helped either.

How can I create those missing class files to correct this problem?

**The files in the build folder are:**

In the build folder there's the `MainClass$1 - 10.class`, `MainClass.form`, `MainClass.class`, `ClassA$1 - 10.class`, `ClassA.form`, `ClassB$1 - 10.class` and `ClassB.form`

Comment: Probably you want to read about the meaning of the *classpath* in Java. And how to structure projects in Netbeans; so that you have clear places where source code and build output files go.

Comment: Is there a main method in all three classes?

Comment: @MrunalPagnis yes there are main methods in all three classes

Comment: @Jägermeister Do you have any links that you could refer me to?

Comment: @tirpitz.verus It's a Swing GUI and I compiled/ran it through the Netbeans IDE (Shift + F6)

Comment: Could you please show us your project structure?  A recursive listing of all files in your project directory will do.

Comment: Never put more information into comments; please update your question instead; and delete the comments with that information. And most importantly: how many projects do you have? 1 or 3 ?

Comment: @Jägermeister it's one project

Comment: @BrandonMcKenzie I mentioned the files in an update in my question

Comment: That's helpful, but I'm asking for your project directory; what directory is your netbeans project in, where do your java files live, do you have any resource files?  In addition, are you using a build manager, like ant, maven, gradle?  How are you building your project?